# Null check in an enhanced for loop

Tags: java, syntax, loops, for-loop

What is the best way to guard against null in a for loop in Java?

This seems ugly :

```
if (someList != null) {
    for (Object object : someList) {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

Or

```
if (someList == null) {
    return; // Or throw ex
}
for (Object object : someList) {
    // do whatever
}
```

There might not be any other way. Should they have put it in the `for` construct itself, if it is null then don't run the loop?

Comment: You are probably better off throwing an NPE. `null` is not the same as an empty collection.

Comment: @GregMattes How February question is a duplicate of October question?

Comment: Just need to use Collections.nonNullElementsIn(...): http://stackoverflow.com/a/34913556/5637185

Answer (score 255, accepted):

You should better verify where you get that list from.

An empty list is all you need, because an empty list won't fail.

If you get this list from somewhere else and don't know if it is ok or not you could create a utility method and use it like this:

```
for( Object o : safe( list ) ) {
   // do whatever 
 }
```

And of course `safe` would be:

```
public static List safe( List other ) {
    return other == null ? Collections.EMPTY_LIST : other;
}
```

Comment: Note that Collections.emptyList() will avoid allocating an extra object (IIRC).

Comment: @Jon: I have always asked my self, what was the use of that `emptyList` http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList()   What's IIRC?

Comment: IIRC = "If I recall correctly". And yes, there is a singleton instance that is returned for all calls to Collections.emptyList().

Comment: This ... doesn't actually answer the question. Why is it accepted answer?

Comment: @ChristopherWirt because it does answer the question :D

Comment: Very cool example and direct. 
Only one tip. Both: EMPTY_LIST and emptyList() allocate one new instance.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind though with `Collections.emptyList()`, the list is immutable, you can add any items to it. If you are just reading from the list, then this is fine, but if you want to add items you will need a new list object. IIRC if you do try to add to a `Collections.emptyList()`, the error message isn't the most helpful.

Comment: You can always use `commons-lang`'s `ArrayUtil` class. See [nullToEmpty](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#nullToEmpty(java.lang.Object[])) methods.

Comment: Both `Collections.emptyList` and `Collections.EMPTY_LIST` return `public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new EmptyList<Object>();`

Comment: Instead of Collections.emptyList() and Collectiosn.EMPTY_LIST, could it be also OK to return a new ArrayList<T> with zero capacity?

Comment: @RobertoLinares that's technically fine but if you have no plans to add items to the list it's more efficient to use one of the options from Collections. Going back to the original question, the intention here is to avoid hitting a NullPointerException so making a brand new List wouldn't benefit you.

Answer (score 107):

You could potentially write a helper method which returned an empty sequence if you passed in null:

```
public static <T> Iterable<T> emptyIfNull(Iterable<T> iterable) {
    return iterable == null ? Collections.<T>emptyList() : iterable;
}
```

Then use:

```
for (Object object : emptyIfNull(someList)) {
}
```

I don't think I'd actually do that though - I'd usually use your second form. In particular, the "or throw ex" is important - if it really shouldn't be null, you should definitely throw an exception. You know that *something* has gone wrong, but you don't know the extent of the damage. Abort early.

Comment: I would change the Iterable<T> list parameter to Iterable<T> iterable, as not every iterable is a list.

Comment: Be careful using this method: because of use of Collections class, the use of this method involve your list te be immutable

Comment: @tanorix: In what way?

Comment: @JonSkeet you can see that emptyList() of Collections class return an immutable list : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList-- so if the user do not want to have his list immutable it can be problematic

Comment: @tanorix: But the point of this question is about *iterating* over the returned value. That doesn't modify it. That's why the return type of `emptyIfNull` is `Iterable<T>` - there's the unfortunate `remove` method on `Iterator<T>`, but that's the only mutable aspect of it (and if you've got an empty collection, why are you trying to remove anything from it?) It's not clear what you're objecting to here.

Answer (score 42):

It's already 2017, and you can now use [Apache Commons Collections4](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/)

The usage:

```
for(Object obj : ListUtils.emptyIfNull(list1)){
    // Do your stuff
}
```

You can do the same null-safe check to other Collection classes with `CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull`.

Comment: Will work though creates unnecessary list object. A CollectionUtils.ifNotEmpty may be more verbose but more efficient and faster. Not that it would matter much...

Comment: In 2017 I would expect List.emptyIfNull(list1)

Comment: @Lawrence, the method doesn't create new list objects, it uses `Collections.emptyList()` internally, which in its turn always returns the same preallocated empty unmodifiable list.

Comment: What if you call myobject.getCompanies().getAddresses() and both return a List and both can be null?

Answer (score 14):

With Java 8 `Optional`:

```java
for (Object object : Optional.ofNullable(someList).orElse(Collections.emptyList())) {
    // do whatever
}
```

Comment: Its more verbose than simple ternary operator like `someList != null ? someList : Collections.emptyList()` and also creates and immediately throws away an instance of `Optional` object.

Comment: how are these monster lines more elegant than a simple if(someList==null) statement. Let's write a bank application in one line...

Comment: if you want to go this way then with use of static import it would look slightly better: `ofNullable(someList).orElse(emptyList()))`

Answer (score 13):

Use `ArrayUtils.nullToEmpty` from the `commons-lang` library for Arrays

```
for( Object o : ArrayUtils.nullToEmpty(list) ) {
   // do whatever 
}
```

This functionality exists in the `commons-lang` library, which is included in most Java projects.

```
// ArrayUtils.nullToEmpty source code 
public static Object[] nullToEmpty(final Object[] array) {
    if (isEmpty(array)) {
        return EMPTY_OBJECT_ARRAY;
    }
    return array;
}

// ArrayUtils.isEmpty source code
public static boolean isEmpty(final Object[] array) {
    return array == null || array.length == 0;
}
```

This is the same as the answer given by @OscarRyz, but for the sake of the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) mantra, I believe it is worth noting. See the [commons-lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) project page. Here is the `nullToEmpty` API [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#nullToEmpty(java.lang.Object[])) and [source](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#line.474)

Maven entry to include `commons-lang` in your project if it is not already.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Unfortunately, `commons-lang` doesn't provide this functionality for `List` types. In this case you would have to use a helper method as previously mentioned.

```
public static <E> List<E> nullToEmpty(List<E> list)
{
    if(list == null || list.isEmpty())
    {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are getting that `List` from a method call that you implement, then don't return `null`, return an empty `List`.

If you can't change the implementation then you are stuck with the `null` check. If it should't be `null`, then throw an exception.

I would not go for the helper method that returns an empty list because it may be useful some times but then you would get used to call it in every loop you make possibly hiding some bugs.

Answer (score 4):

I have modified the above answer, so you don't need to cast from Object

```
public static <T> List<T> safeClient( List<T> other ) {
            return other == null ? Collections.EMPTY_LIST : other;
}
```

and then simply call the List by

```
for (MyOwnObject ownObject : safeClient(someList)) {
    // do whatever
}
```

Explaination:
MyOwnObject: If `List<Integer>` then MyOwnObject will be Integer in this case.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone uninterested in writing their own static null safety method you can use: commons-lang's `org.apache.commons.lang.ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull(Object, Object)`. For example:

```
    for (final String item : 
    (List<String>)ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull(items, Collections.emptyList())) { ... }
```

[ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull JavaDoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#defaultIfNull(T,%20T))

Comment: For me, this answer is the most elegant

Comment: Another similar approach using Java's native `Objects` class is`Objects.requireNonNullElse(itemsList, new ArrayList<String>())`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to effectively guard against a null in a for loop is to wrap your collection with Google Guava's [`Optional<T>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) as this, one hopes, makes the possibility of an effectively empty collection clear since the client would be expected to check if the collection is present with `Optional.isPresent()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use, `CollectionUtils.isEmpty(Collection coll)` method which is Null-safe check if the specified collection is empty.

for this `import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils`.

Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -5):

```
for (Object object : someList) {

   // do whatever
}  throws the null pointer exception.
```