# Why enhanced for loop is not performing the null checking

Tags: java

Why the enhanced for loop is not performing null checking before iterating over the collection.

Comment: can you specify some more details about your code and what you are doing ?

Comment: I imagine the question is about why `for (X y : (List<X>)null) { ... }` is throwing an NPE...

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250031

Comment: possible duplicate of [Null check in an enhanced for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250031/null-check-in-an-enhanced-for-loop)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you mean that this would go bang:

```
int[] array = null;
for (int x : array) {
}
```

... then I think it's entirely proper for that to throw a `NullPointerException`. The alternative would be for it to silently swallow the null, and treat that as equivalent to an empty array. That's not the approach Java takes anywhere else - why should this be different? It would make the language inconsistent.

The one place I wish there *were* more handling (but explicit handling) is switching on an enum - it would be nice to be able to provide a case for null, to avoid checking for that one special value beforehand. But that's a very different construct, which is specifically trying to take different actions for different values.

Comment: A `null` case for switching on enums is an interesting idea, but what should happen if you have a `default:` but no explicit `case null:` and the enum value is `null`.  If the `null` goes to the default case that breaks backwards compatibility, and is bad if `null` is an erroneous value.  If you get an NPE, then `default` is behaving in a semantically inconsistent way.  (It now means "default unless its null ...")

Comment: @Stephen C: Good questions. I'm not sure that it's a good idea to introduce it *now*, but I think it would have been nice to consider when the feature was first introduced.

Comment: I think there are enough "wrinkles" that it would (hypothetically) have been a bad idea even then.  Maybe if Java 1.0 had also had nullable tyoes ...

Comment: "It would make the language inconsistent." - yes, that is a problem, but not for the reason you say it is. It would be a single, rare, moment in Java where it actually wouldn't be a PITA language to use. I feel like the people creating Java looked at languages that had come before, like C and Python, and decided, "Lets make this more difficult to use than C, but have the performance of Python." I have no idea how Java ever became a language people actually chose to use when there's a whole universe of better languages, either being easier to use or having much better performance.

Answer (score 5):

I kind of afraid to assert against Jon Skeet... :| ...
But what a hell... what do you think about this scenario?:

`

```
findMoney(List<Places> places){
   int money = 0;
   for(Place place : places){
   money += searchWithCare(place);
   }
return money;
}
```

`

If I ask some client to tell me where to look and he tells me nothing. Do you think is better here to throw a NullPointerException? May be manage the call to this method so if parameter is null not call it?....
I think that return 0 is a consistent response because no error is here. I believe Exceptions are made to manage flow of code and I dont see why should I change the flow in this kind of situation. Return a cero or even a null could be a good response, couldnt it be?

So what about this solution?
`

```
findMoney(List<Places> places){
   int money = 0;
   for(Place place : places == null ?Collections.<Place>emptyList():places){
   money += searchWithCare(place);
   }
return money;
}
```

`

Comment: This was really helpful. I've never seen the `Collections.<Place>emptyList()` idiom before. I'd have expected it to be `Collections.emptyList<Place>()` if you could do that, but apparently not. Do you know where this idiom is documented? I'm having trouble finding it.

Comment: I was trying to find it! I couldn't... it is a.. secret? :) Sorry

Comment: Oh well, thanks for trying anyway. It's kin of hard to search for.

Comment: For generic methods, docs.oracle says "The type has been explicitly provided [...]. Generally, this can be left out and the compiler will infer the type that is needed"

Answer (score 1):

The code must be like this:

```
for (AnyObject anyObject : checkIsEmpty(anyObjectList)) {
        System.out.println(anyObject.doSomething());
}

private <T> Iterable<T> checkIsEmpty(Iterable<T> iterable) {
        return iterable == null ? Collections.<T>emptyList() : iterable;
}
```