# Is there a way to avoid null check before the for-each loop iteration starts?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

Every time I have to iterate over a collection I end up checking for null, just before the iteration of the for-each loop starts. Like this:

```
if( list1 != null ){
    for(Object obj : list1){

    }
}
```

Is there a shorter way, so that we can avoid writing the "if" block ?
Note: I am using Java 5, and will be stuck with it for sometime.

Comment: Like SLaks said, your collections should not be null instead their size be zero. In that case, the enhanced for loop doesn't error out.

Comment: you can remove the block of the if and it would have the same effect

Comment: @ratchet I can't remove the "if" block. If in case the list1 is null, then there will be NullPointerException

Comment: I meant that you type `if(list1 != null)for(Object obj : list1){...}` in other words remove the curly braces around for this way you can keep it in one line

Comment: @ratchet   Interesting... but I probably won't get that pass the code review :)

Comment: I guess the right answer is that: there is no way to make it shorter.

there are  some techniques such as the ones in the comments, but I don't see myself using them. I think it's better to write a "if" block than to use those techniques.

and yes..  before anybody mentions it yet again :)   "ideally" the code should be desgined such that list should never be a null.

Comment: You need to show us more code. How are you getting a null list?

Comment: This is not a foreach loop. Its an enhanced for loop.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I guess the right answer is that: there is no way to make it shorter. There are some techniques such as the ones in the comments, but I don't see myself using them. I think it's better to write a "if" block than to use those techniques. and yes.. before anybody mentions it yet again :) "ideally" the code should be desgined such that list should never be a **null**

Answer (score 101):

If possible, you should design your code such that the collections aren't `null` in the first place.

`null` collections are bad practice (for this reason); you should use empty collections instead. (eg, [`Collections.emptyList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList()))

Alternatively, you could make a wrapper class that implements `Iterable` and takes a collections, and handles a `null` collection.
You could then write `foreach(T obj : new Nullable<T>(list1))`

Comment: I am just one of the developers...  a lowly ranked one at that :)

Comment: if you're using generics it's better to use Collections.emptyList() rather than Collections.EMPTY_LIST; it's type safe.

Comment: @Dataknife More like it just does the casting for you.  There are no generics types at runtime with either case, and the implementation of `emptyList()` internally contains the cast (with a suppression on unchecked too).

Comment: This turned out to be bad design for me. The place I placed them was then used by JAX - B to unmarshall data These lists are immutable and it would try and add to them. I think you should consider this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552258/collections-emptylist-vs-new-instance

Comment: And empty list works great when you have the idea of a collection with nothing in it.  That is subtly different than no collection; and, the difference can be significant.  For example, when optional lists are represented as empty ones, you have to choose between handling it as a list or as nothing (the simplification removes one of the two options).  This can be undesirable in some situations.

Comment: How is having an empty collection a good practice? Isn't this going to be using a lo t of memory? In applications where milliseconds matters this would be the best to do also?

Answer (score 54):

```
public <T extends Iterable> T nullGuard(T item) {
  if (item == null) {
    return Collections.EmptyList;
  } else {
    return item;
  }
}
```

or, if saving lines of text is a priority (it shouldn't be)

```
public <T extends Iterable> T nullGuard(T item) {
  return (item == null) ? Collections.EmptyList : item;
}
```

would allow you to write

```
for (Object obj : nullGuard(list)) {
  ...
}
```

Of course, this really just moves the complexity elsewhere.

Comment: Good answer, but probably should be a static.

Comment: It does not just "move the complexity elsewhere". It encapsulates the complexity in one place, so you don't have to write that null-checking code again and again. The question was how to make it shorter. The check has to be done **somewhere**. You are very humble, @edwin-buck

Comment: public <T extends Iterable> T nullGuard(T item) {
  if (item == null) {
    return Collections.EmptyList;
  } 
    return item;
  }

Comment: @corroborator Yes, that saves the "else" statement by doing a short-circuit return.  It is an equivalent code flow.   I updated to have an even smaller solution; but, really saving lines of text should be secondary in priority to easy to read code.  Not sure what the style is in the place where this solution might be used; but, mimic it's style (not a personal one) if a dominant style exists.

Answer (score 45):

It's already 2017, and you can now use [Apache Commons Collections4](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/)

The usage:

```
for(Object obj : CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(list1)){
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: This is the most cleanest answer I have seen here. Is there a way to do the same if my list1 is a Object array i.e., Object[]?

Comment: `for(Object obj : ArrayUtils.nullToEmpty(list1)) {
    // Do your stuff
}`

Answer (score 33):

In Java 8 there is another solution available by using `java.util.Optional` and the `ifPresent`-method.

```
Optional.ofNullable(list1).ifPresent(l -> l.forEach(item -> {/* do stuff */}));
```

So, not a solution for the exact problem but it is a oneliner and possibly more elegant.

Comment: Java 8 `Optional` is a case of the cure being a bit worse than the disease.  `Optional` is a verbose and clunky replacement for a simple null check.  To be avoided, imo.

Comment: @CharlieReitzel absolutely! But if the code-base is very null-value-oriented, I find this approach working pretty well for me: Cleaner version of a null check. I would definitely recommend this `Optional.ofNullable()`.

Comment: Less code, less bugs.   `if ( null != foo ) ...` looks _a lot_ cleaner to me than `Optional.ofNullable(foo).ifPresent( xfoo -> ... );`   But, of course, you may feel differently.

Answer (score 17):

[Null check in an enhanced for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250031/null-check-in-an-enhanced-for-loop)

```
public static <T> Iterable<T> emptyIfNull(Iterable<T> iterable) {
    return iterable == null ? Collections.<T>emptyList() : iterable;
}
```

Then use:

```
for (Object object : emptyIfNull(someList)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 17):

Apache Commons

```
for (String code: ListUtils.emptyIfNull(codes)) {

}
```

Google Guava

```
for (String code: Optional.of(codes).get()) {

}
```

Answer (score 7):

How much shorter do you want it to be? It is only an extra 2 lines AND it is clear and concise logic.

I think the more important thing you need to decide is if `null` is a valid value or not. If they are not valid, you should write you code to prevent it from happening. Then you would not need this kind of check. If you go get an exception while doing a `foreach` loop, that is a sign that there is a bug somewhere else in your code.

Comment: unfortunately in many situation touching methods that gives these lists can create problems for me...  It won't be the first time where I saw methods "expecting" null to be returned by other methods..

Comment: I was wondering it could be shorter, because I recently came across some Groovy code that checks for null using "?"..  forgot what its called.

Comment: The ternary operrator.

Answer (score 6):

1) if list1 is a member of a class, create the list in the constructor so it's there and non-null though empty.

2) for (Object obj : list1 != null ? list1 : new ArrayList())

Comment: interesting.. will be trying it out

Comment: Much better to use Collections.emptyList().  Why allocate something just to garbage collect it?

Comment: inspired like this comment I wrote at utility class :                                                    
`public static <T> List<T> ofNullable(List<T> list) {return list == null ? Collections.emptyList() : list;}`  and then use: ` for (Object obj : ofNullable(list1)) {`

Answer (score 3):

Another Java 8+ way would be to create a forEach method that does not crash when using a `null` value:

```
public static <T> void forEach(Iterable<T> set, Consumer<T> action) {
    if (set != null) {
        set.forEach(action);
    }
}
```

The usage of the own defined `foreach` is close to the native Java 8 one:

```
ArrayList<T> list = null;

//java 8+ (will throw a NullPointerException)
list.forEach(item -> doSomething(...) );

//own implementation
forEach(list, item -> doSomething(...) );
```