# java.lang.NullPointerException when scanning directories

Tags: java, io, nullpointerexception

I have a very simple method that scans a directory structure to perform a check. The scanning looking like this:

```
File file = new File(initpath);

for(File hex : file.listFiles(new HexagonNameFilter())) {

    for(File wall : hex.listFiles()) {

        for(File shelf : wall.listFiles()) {

            for(File book : shelf.listFiles()) {

                // Perform some actual work
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

The method is called lots of times during the execution of the program.

Inconsistently (meaning, at some unpredictable point in the scanning process), I get a java.lang.NullPointerException with the stack trace pointing at one of the for statements (which one it is is also inconsistent). This is not enlightening. I was thinking of passing FilenameFilters to the three listFiles() calls, but can't see how that would help the issue.

Comment: Bad news: `listFiles` may return null: so you need a `File[]` variable and an if-statement. Or make wrap listFiles in your own function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077909/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-null-check-before-the-for-each-loop-iteration-starts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should verify that you are calling this method on a directory. Otherwise, it returns null.

> listFiles
>
> public File[] listFiles()
>
> Returns an array of abstract pathnames denoting the files in the
>   directory denoted by this abstract pathname.
>
> If this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, then this
>   method **returns null**. Otherwise an array of File objects is returned,
>   one for each file or directory in the directory. Pathnames denoting
>   the directory itself and the directory's parent directory are not
>   included in the result. Each resulting abstract pathname is
>   constructed from this abstract pathname using the File(File, String)
>   constructor. Therefore if this pathname is absolute then each
>   resulting pathname is absolute; if this pathname is relative then each
>   resulting pathname will be relative to the same directory.
>
> There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array
>   will appear in  any specific order; they are not, in particular,
>   guaranteed to appear in alphabetical order.
>
> Returns: An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and
>   directories in the  directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The
>   array will be empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this
>   abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error
>   occurs.

Comment: Thanks and I think that helps solve the problem. I will try using a FileFilter or FilenameFilter to make absolutely sure only the directories I want to scan are scanned. What confused me was I knew the directories I was scanning were definitely not empty and existed - hence the lack of checks. As it is however, I now see I might be calling the method on dot-files!