# Can we add additional stopping condition in iterator for-loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, coding-style

In the conventional loop, we could have as below, making single nested layer.

```
for (int i=0; listObject != null && i < listObject.size(); i++) {
    // Do whatever we want
}
```

However, using the below style for each loop, I'll need a double nested code: -

```
if (listObject != null) {
    for (Object object: listObject) {
        // Do whatever we want
    }
}
```

Is it possible to embed the `listObject != null` condition into the for-loop statement to make it single nested code?

Comment: Why do you need to check if `listObject` is null during each iteration of the loop? Is there code somewhere that might dereference it?

Comment: Same question IMO was already asked there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077909/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-null-check-before-the-for-each-loop-iteration-starts

Comment: The "null" check is a more typical case of example. It idea is, if we have another condition to check, is there a way to still make it single nested. I have provided my version of answer below. Thanks!

Comment: To have a flatter code structure, I may do a normalization first like `if(list==null) list=emptyList();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second example is clear, easily understood code.  There is nothing wrong with nesting a for loop in an if block.  It's even more clear than your first example.

But if you insist on combining them, you can use the ternary operator to supply an empty list if `listObject` is null.  Using `Collections.emptyList` means no iterations will take place and no `NullPointerException` will be thrown.

```
for (Object object : listObject == null ? Collections.emptyList() : listObject)
```

I don't think I would use code like this when a clear example such as your second example already exists, but this code does provide a way to get two colons inside a `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks @rgettman. I'll give a tick to this answer given it's answering my question directly. I have my own version of approach though not as direct. Will write as one answer to this as well (check it out and comment if any). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make it concise on, while having a single nested loop, I decided to make it into function as below

```
void checkCondition(List<Object> listObject) {
   if (listObject == null) return;

   for (Object object: listObject) {
       // Do whatever
   }
}
```