# Iterator null collection

Tags: java, collections, iterator

It's quite common that I have to check null before iterate when not sure the collection reference is null or not.
Sample:

```
Collection<Object> collection = ...
...
if(collection != null)//troublesome
    for(Object o : collection)
```

Of course, I know empty collection is much better than null, but in some cases client code cannot control the nullable collection from other modules (for instance, return value from 3rd party code).
So I wrote a utility method:

```
public static <T> Iterable<T> nullableIterable(Iterable<T> it){
    return it != null ? it : Collections.<T>emptySet();
}
```

In client code, no need to check null any more:

```
for(Object o : nullableIterable(collection))
...
```

Do you think `nullableIterable()` is reasonable? Any advice? Any concern? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I do that too. My method is called `nullSafe()`...

Comment: @LukasEder What default Iterable instance does nullSafe() return?

Comment: I overloaded `nullSafe(List)`, `nullSafe(Set)`, etc. in a utility class... But your idea works as well, as you only expose the `Iterable` type. Concrete `Iterable` implementations shouldn't matter to the call-site

Comment: And if somebody choose to do code defensive by ignoring nulls, Here is nice way http://stackoverflow.com/a/2250056/1506477

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks good. I personally do that too. You will always get developers who would disagree with this as it is kind of defensive programming. Imagine you have a workflow or a class that is not supposed to return `null`. This means that getting a `null` from it is a bug which your code will hide as it will turn the `null` to an empty collection and the bug will never surface.

If you are for example writing APIs that do not support `null` collections then you should avoid this. If client code gives you a `null` collection where you do not support it, you should throw an `IllegalArgumentException` to let client code know that there is something wrong with the provided collection. Something like:

```
public void myApiNoSupportForNull(Collection<Object> collection){
   // Pre condition
   if(collection == null) 
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("This API does not support null collections!");
   //...
}
```

Comment: Agreed. So I should tell the client code how to use the method and notice the pitfall. I may wrote some Javadoc for the method.

Comment: Or throw an `IllegalArgumentException` and return so that client code will know that you do not support `null` collections

Comment: *some* may argue like that, yes. But *some* API's are designed to both "support" `null` and empty lists. Take `File.list()` for instance. It can return `null` on some occasions, which aren't necessarily errors. N.B: Also for *some* API's, it may be convenient to accept `null` as a substitute for empty collections, if the semantics would be the same

Comment: @LukasEder I totally agree with you. It all depend on the API you are exposing.

Comment: Why do you claim it is a bug? I have such design and I think that collection is not initialized for performance. Why is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

This looks good to me if you limit usage of this function to the layer that interacts with "external" code and make sure you will never start using it for defense from yourself or from your colleagues.
Consider annotate parameters and fields within your code with @Nullable annotation - assuming that what is not annotated cannot be null, pretty helpful especially taking into account that IDEs and static analysis tools are aware of this annotation.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases this would be OK. 
Bare in mind you might encounter third parties that return null in case of error , and that an empty list is a valid result. 
I would therefore consider to alter a bit your code and do something like this:

```
public static <T> Iterable<T> nullableIterable(Iterable<T> it, boolean exceptionIfNull){
    if (exceptionIfNull && it == null) {
        throw new NUllPointerException("Iterable is null");
    } else
    return it != null ? it : Collections.<T>emptySet();
}

public static <T> Iterable<T> nullableIterable(Iterable<T> it){
    return nul,lableIterable(it,false); //Default behavior for most cases
}
```