# Avoiding Null Pointer Exception in "for" statement

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

In my code I usually use this approach to avoid `NullPointerException`s in for statements when a `List` is null:

```
if (myList != null && myList.size() > 0) {
    for ( MyObj obj : myList ) {
        System.out.println("MyObjStr: "+obj);
    }
}
```

Is there another way to do the same without write the "if" statement, but using the same "for" statement?

Comment: If you have initialized `myList`, there is no reason to check if it's `null` unless in some point you explicitly assign `null` to it. Regarding the size, you don't have to check it.

Comment: you can easily avoid collection to be null by calling it's constructor. In such a case you'll have non-null, but empty collection. If so, you don't even need size check

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077909/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-null-check-before-the-for-each-loop-iteration-starts

Comment: I was wondering that if you are checking that <code>myList</code> is not <code>null</code> then where you need to check whether <code>myList</code> size is greater than 0? What I mean here is that if your list is not null, then it must have size and lists can't have negative sizes, so I think <code>myList.size() > 0</code> is not necessary in your case, unless it is initialized.

Comment: @AmirAl The size check was to prevent the size from being 0, not from being negative. Even if a list is initialized, it could have a size of 0 (actually it does if you don't add any item). **Anyway, this check is not needed since the `for` loop does not do anything on an empty list**.

Comment: @Joffrey you are correct, but still my aim was that check is not required as you said :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the size check is not needed. The for loop is skipped if the size is 0.

The null check is a bit more contextual. In general you don't want to just "avoid NPE". NPE is a good way to notice programming mistakes, so you have to be careful about what needs to be null-checked. Many programmers put null-checks everywhere defensively, because they don't trust the API contracts anymore.

- If you have an NPE with something that has **no reason to be null**, then you have done something wrong earlier (here it would be because your collection variable is not initialized). You don't want to hide that, you want it to explode at your face, so you can fix it right away (**Fail fast principle**).
- If **`null` is a possible (and meaningful) value** for a variable (or if the value comes from an external source), then it needs to be null-checked. However, you have to handle that case, do not just skip the code that produces NPE. If you just skip it, then later code is no more safe than the current piece, and null-checks will be needed again for the same variable.

@ifLoop provided a very good link to another post about this topic, so I copy it here since my answer is accepted:
[Avoiding “!= null” statements in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java/271874#271874)

Comment: Lot of debates about this... I don't think it should by applied anywhere. For example you don't want your app to go down if an external service you depend on starts returning null collections...

Comment: Of course, I totally agree with you. I don't say you don't want null checks. I said you don't want to just "avoid NPEs". If `null` is apossible value for an external input (and several other cases), then the check has to be done and handled properly. However, if something has no reason to be null at one point, then don't put a null check, it hides errors.

Comment: In our specific case, the null check is not used to handle a special case, but just to skip the error and hide it, which IMHO is bad.

Comment: i think the inventor admits that null is a billion dollar mistake - 
https://medium.com/.../null-pointer-references-the-billion-dollar-mistake-1e616534d485

Answer (score 12):

The check for the size is not needed. Your for-loop will not execute if is there are no objects in the list. 

The check for `null` is only needed, when you are not sure about the object's state. But when using your own objects (nothing given from outside via arguements e.g.) then there is no need for the null check.

See [Avoiding “!= null” statements in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java/271874#271874) for a brilliant explanation why unexperienced developers often exaggregate with null checks.

Answer (score 5):

An elegant way to do this, can be found in a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250031/null-check-in-an-enhanced-for-loop). using

```
for( Object o : safe( list ) ) {
   // do whatever 
 }

public static List safe( List other ) {
    return other == null ? Collections.EMPTY_LIST : other;
}
```

That beeing said, it's a good practice to have your methods returning empty Arrays instead of null. For example you can return

```
return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
```

in every `catch` block.

This way you will loop in them safely, and when you get a NPE, you'll know that something is wrong with your **code, not your data**. In this context, as @Joffrey said, the NPE will be really welcome

Comment: In the given solutions this is the most elegant

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do it one line but with a readability loss :

```
for ( MyObj obj : (myList == null ? new ArrayList<MyObj>() : myList) ) {
    System.out.println("MyObjStr: "+obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another possibility to avoid passing NULL into our for (forEach) loop - we can use **isNotEmpty(Collection coll)** method from **CollectionUtils** library before.

**Example:**

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(someCollection)) {
    for (Item item: someCollection) {
    ...
    }
}
```

**OR:**

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(someCollection)) {
    someCollection.forEach(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of cases when you are supposed to do a mapping exercise for incoming DTO into another Object. Sending empty collections instead of null can be a waste of traffic, and even nulls are excluded by using 
`mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);` or even `mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);`

That said, if you need to do something like:

```
Collection<Dto> dtos = null;
for(Dto dto: dtos) {
   //doSomething
}
```

You have to protect with `if`(ok, but I prefer another way) or stick to NullObject idiom(good):

```
Collection<Dto> safeDtos = Optional.ofNullable(dtos).orElse(Collections.emptyList());
for(Dto dto: safeDtos) {
   //doSomething
}
```

Or the same but for streams:

```
Optional.ofNullable(dtos).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream()
    .map(this::doSomething)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Also, try not to leak DTOs in any downstream code except that mapping exercise. You should have a border of protection between DTO and the rest of your code.

DTO -> Mapping -> Domain Object(or another intermediate object which is NPE save and maybe has enums instead of strings, etc) -> Rest of your code.