# Best way to add validation incase a list returns null?

Tags: java, string, validation, for-loop, set

I have the following code within my `Java` application:

```
 for (String s: personService.returnNames(){

       //do something
    }
```

Note: the return value of `returnNames()` is a `set` of Strings

How can I best `validate` this code so that even if no Strings are returned the application does not crash?

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with validation.
What about a simple `if(personService.returnNames()!=null)` ?

Comment: I am assuming by `validation` you mean `unit testing` ? Then something like `Assert.assertnotNull( personService.returnNames() )`

Comment: More explanations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250031/null-check-in-an-enhanced-for-loop

Comment: If no Strings are returned, the method should return an empty Set, not `null`. Do you have control over the method `retrunNames`?

Answer (score 0):

Does that mean the method returns an empty List or a null List?

If the list is empty then nothing bad happens, the for loop just doesn't run. If the List can be null then you need an implicit check before, e.g.

```
if(personService.returnNames() != null) {
    for (String s: personService.returnNames(){
       //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: If the List can be null then yes.

Answer (score 0):

The **real** answer: simply avoid null as return value. Of course, you can put a (set != null) check in front of everything. But you don't want that.

And especially, when your method is supposed to return **any** kind of collection, that is really easy. Because: you return an empty instance of that collection in such cases!

So, in your case, you could do

A) rename "returnNames" into something more meaningful, such as "getNames"

and within the PersonService class you could do something like:

```
class PersonService {
  private final Set<String> EMPTY_NAMES = Collections.emptySet();

  String getNames() {
    ... if no names are stored yet
    return EMPTY_LINES
```

[ disclaimer: one shouldn't try to **add** anything to a set that was created that way; because that causes an exception ]

Answer (score 0):

```
Collection<String> returnedNames=personService.returnNames();
if(returnedNames!=null){
    for (String s: returnedNames){
       //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: The Yoda pattern avoid you should: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions ... in Java (whatever = null) will not compile; therefore there is no point in making it harder to read by reversing the two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

How about optional and stream?

```
    Optional.of(personService.returnNames())
            .ifPresent(
                    o -> o.stream()
                            .filter(s -> s != null)
                            .forEach(s -> {
                                //something
                            })
            );
```

Fix.