# check for null using conditional operators in java

Tags: java, java-8

I have to repeat code like this many times:

```
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(line[9])) {
    tbl.setVal(line[9].charAt(0));
}
```

Can I clean this code up, make it inline, like a conditional operator?  I've seen examples with C# but am having trouble finding a similar java example.

Or can I abstract this out into a function?  A generic function that could handle multiple types?

My goal here is if the value of `line[x]` is empty, I do not want to call `setVal`

Comment: There is difference between `null` and `empty`

Comment: @Ravi i just updated the post...if the value of the string `line` is empty, I want the object in `tbl` to not be set.

Comment: The operands of the conditional operator are expressions, not statements, and statements are not expressions in Java. Your title still says `null`.

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem. If you're repeating those lines many times, restructuring them individually is not going to help much. You need to approach the code from a higher level and see what you can do to avoid repetition in the first place.

Comment: @Holger ha! I've tried to show the same approach...

Answer (score 3):

You can create method like this:

```
public static void applyIfNotEmpty(Consumer<String> consumer, String value) {
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
        consumer.accept(value);
    }
}
```

And then use it in such way:

```
applyIfNotEmpty(v -> tbl.setVal(v.charAt(0)), line[9]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have a function like

```
private void setValueInTbl(String input) {
  if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(input) {
    tbl.setVal(input.charAt(0));
  }
}
```

Then you could call it like this

```
setValueInTbl(line[9]);
```

Also, the ternary operator is not ideal because [you need two values to give it after evaluation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

Comment: As you are probably aware, a return is not required for a void method, but it can have it. Personally, I think it improves readability even though it is not necessary. [More on return in a void method is explained by Oracle here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html).

Comment: Sure I am aware, but sorry, have to contradict. It does *not* improve readability. It is just obsolete code without any value. Why don't you write `if(true) return; else return;` instead? Same useless code... By the way: The link you provided does not recommend to place a return at the very end either.

Comment: No need to be sorry, seems I made a mistake. I will remove the line from the original answer. For clarification, I let a matter of opinion enter into an answer and in so doing disregarded the rules for posting an answer (no opinions).

Answer (score 0):

The clever way to go about this is to create a generic method like you said. However, there is a difference between a null variable and an empty variable.

To check null variables you are better off throwing an NPE.

Also, have a look at this link if you are checking elements in a list, it is an elegant solution.
[Null check in an enhanced for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250031/null-check-in-an-enhanced-for-loop)

Other methods that you could use to achieve this are:

```
Validate.notNull(variable)
Validate.notEmpty(variable) - Depending on what you really want to check for.
```

These validations will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` based on their condition.

Found this as well... worth a read!
[Java: How to check for null pointers efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795455/java-how-to-check-for-null-pointers-efficiently)

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a method to deal with that *generally*, not just for `String` and `notEmpty`:

```
public static <T> void consumeIf(Consumer<T> consumer, T value, Predicate<T> predicate) {
    Optional.ofNullable(value).filter(predicate).ifPresent(consumer);
}
```